# OR operator not working in mysql php

Tags: php, mysql

I need help in issue related to MySQL database OR Operator, I am new to MySQL database so I am facing problems. Actually, I am building search engine filter. 
I am getting two values from another page and show them on a search page by filtering from the database. 
Here I declare values that come from another page

```
$cid = $_GET['cid'];
$plateform = $_GET['plateform'];
```

And here is my SQL

```
SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE (Cat_id = $cid) OR (plateform_id IN ($plateform)
```

when I try to get two values it gives me error like and when I get one value it works well. help me solve this problem.
It gives me an error , given below

```
mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in
```

Comment: Are you missing a close bracket at the end.

Comment: SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE (Cat_id = $cid) OR (plateform_id IN ($plateform))

Comment: See about prepared statements. Also, it's more useful if you post all relevant code, rather than just snippets.

Answer (score 1):

```
you are missed close parenthesis at the end.
```

Need to change:

```
SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE (Cat_id = $cid) OR (plateform_id IN ($plateform)
```

To:

```
SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE (Cat_id = $cid) OR (plateform_id IN ($plateform))
```

Or you can also modify your query.

```
SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE Cat_id = $cid OR plateform_id IN ($plateform)
```